# How to convert some values to negative in a column

Tags: r, dplyr

```
my_df <- df %>%
mutate(incExpChange= case_when(
(incNextYear == 'Higher' & INEXQ2 %in% 0:95) ~ INEXQ2,
(incNextYear == 'Lower' & INEXQ2 %in% 0:95) ~ -INEXQ2))
```

I have two columns 'incNextYear' & 'INEXQ2', I want to convert some positive values in 'INEXQ2' to negative in my new column when incNextYear is 'Lower'. -INEXQ2 is not working for me. What am I doing wrong?

```
 structure(list(rID = 1:6, region = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("West", "Northeast", "South", "Midwest"), class = "factor"), incNextYear = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Higher", "Lower", "About the same", "DK"), class = "factor"), homeBuying = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("BAD", "GOOD", "PRO-CON"), class = "factor"), REGION = c("West", "Northeast", "South", "Midwest", "West", "Midwest"), INEXQ1 = c("Higher", "Higher", "Higher", "Lower", "Higher", "Lower"), INEXQ2 = c("2", "3", "13", "3", "6", "5"), V204 = c("BAD", "BAD", "BAD", "BAD", "BAD", "BAD")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: I get this error when using. INEXQ2*(-1) Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `incExpChange = case_when(...)`.
Caused by error in `INEXQ2 * (-1)`:
! non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: Please provide a sample of your data, using the output of `dput(head(df))`.

Comment: > dput(head(data3))
structure(list(rID = 1:6, region = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
1L, 4L), .Label = c("West", "Northeast", "South", "Midwest"), class = "factor"), 
    incNextYear = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Higher", 
    "Lower", "About the same", "DK"), class = "factor"), homeBuying = structure(c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("BAD", "GOOD", "PRO-CON"), class = "factor"), 
    REGION = c("West", "Northeast", "South", "Midwest", "West", 
    "Midwest"), INEXQ1 = c("Higher", "Higher", "Higher", "Lower", 
    "Higher", "Lower"),

Comment: INEXQ2 = c("2", "3", "13", "3", "6", 
    "5"), V204 = c("BAD", "BAD", "BAD", "BAD", "BAD", "BAD")), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `type.convert(as.is = TRUE)`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  type.convert(as.is = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(incExpChange= case_when(
    (incNextYear == 'Higher' & INEXQ2 %in% 0:95) ~ INEXQ2,
    (incNextYear == 'Lower' & INEXQ2 %in% 0:95) ~ -INEXQ2))
```

```
  rID region    incNextYear homeBuying REGION    INEXQ1 INEXQ2 V204  incExpChange
  <int> <chr>     <chr>       <chr>      <chr>     <chr>   <int> <chr>        <int>
1     1 West      Higher      BAD        West      Higher      2 BAD              2
2     2 Northeast Higher      BAD        Northeast Higher      3 BAD              3
3     3 South     Higher      BAD        South     Higher     13 BAD             13
4     4 Midwest   Lower       BAD        Midwest   Lower       3 BAD             -3
5     5 West      Higher      BAD        West      Higher      6 BAD              6
6     6 Midwest   Lower       BAD        Midwest   Lower       5 BAD             -5
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
-INEXQ2
```

with

```
INEXQ2*(-1)
```

Replace

```
(incNextYear == 'Higher' & INEXQ2 %in% 0:95)
```

with

```
((incNextYear == 'Higher') && (INEXQ2 %in% 0:95))
```

another expression is also changed like above.

Comment: Thanks for assisting me. I am getting the following error.                                      Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `incExpChange = case_when(...)`.
Caused by error in `INEXQ2 * (-1)`:
! non-numeric argument to binary operator

Comment: see my edited~.